# How can I reattach loose fireplace doors that mount to brick?

Tags: fireplace, fastener

Question is how to attach a wood screw into a larger hole in fire brick. I'm afraid to use metal plugs because of heat expansion. The reason for asking is one of the screws that holds my fireplace doors has come loose.

Here is the picture inside the fireplace showing the hole, the strapping, and the screw that came loose.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a picture of the hole and of the fireplace, so we can see how far it is from the heat source

Comment: Use a lag shield?

Comment: For a quick fix, I would use stranded steel cable in the hole to get traction (make hole smaller and give something for threads to bite into that will also spread the load) and use similar or same screw.

Comment: I used steel wool in the hole instead of stranded steel cable and the screw gripped well. Thanks for the idea.